# check if a word exist in html and append a registered trademark symbol after that word

Tags: php, javascript

good day.

is it possible to check if a word exist in HTML pages and if that word exist, append a **superscript registered trademark symbol** after that word.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748309/find-words-in-html-page-with-javascript this link will help you .... to find

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i realize after a while i don't need to do that. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

php:

```
$document = 'A string containing the contents of the html document.';
str_replace('Nike','Nike&#0153;',$document);
```