# How to trigger code if a specific word is present on a webpage

Tags: javascript, alert

I am extremely new to coding (more specifically javascript) and only really know the very basics. I was wondering if there was an easy way to perhaps give an alert when a certain word or words are displayed on a webpage, for example if i was in an online chat room and someone wrote "noot noot" i could then get an alert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find words in html page with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748309/find-words-in-html-page-with-javascript)

Comment: @David does the answer help you out ?

Answer (score 1):

To search for a specific word in given area you can use the JS function `search()` which returns a value which being greater than 0 means it exists.

If you want to search the whole body of the webpage for example you can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.search("W3Schools");
```

Or of a specific div with id **output** then you can use:

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML.search("W3Schools");
```

See the example below:

```js
var exists = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML.search("root");
if(exists > 0)
{
  alert("root exissts");
}
else
{
  alert("root does not exist");
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
<p>Hello I am root</p><br/>
<span>this is the root</span>

</div>
```