# How do I make a chrome extension that reads the text in the website I'm visiting?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, filereader

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that analyzes the website I'm currently visiting, but I'm not sure how to proceed. I believe I use `chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML()` and `FileReader`, but I wasn't able to find any help online.

For instance, if I'm visiting reddit.com, I want to see if the front page contains the word "peanut". I'm also a bit of a JS newbie, so elaboration would be appreciated.

Note:  I've been attempting this for two days, and I've already sifted through all of the relevant chrome extensions API at developer.chrome.com, JS forums, and YouTube videos; any obvious solutions I've missed are due to my lack of experience in JS.

Below is my code so far. I believe I've correctly captured the current tab as an MHTML file and I get `hello.js:7 (anonymous function)` as an error when I load the extension.

```js
var __name__ = "__main__";

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Compiled Python script in Chrome";
console.log("hello from python");
alert("yeet");
chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({'tabId': 12}, function(binary mhtmlData){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(mhmlData);
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Here is how to make correct question https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You need to try it first yourself and if something not working and you cannot find it in any tutorial or refs, you can ask here. This is not How to or Code writing service.

Comment: Look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: @maximelian1986 I apologize for the lack of clarity. I've been attempting this for two days, and I've already sifted through all of the relevant chrome extensions API at developer.chrome.com

Comment: So show us your code and tell what part of it not working. Chrome extension is javascript, so check for some web page grabbers. Here something about finding word on page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748309/find-words-in-html-page-with-javascript

Comment: @maximelian1986 Thank you for the helpful link, and I've updated my question.

Comment: You are looking for [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Content script runs on the page you visit and it can send messages to the main script of the extension.