# Finding words from a list on a page

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

I'm currently working on a script that detects bad words and sends out an alert when the word occurs.

I'm using puppeteer, it has access to the chrome browser and it's able to run command in the terminal. I have tried a lot of things in the console, for example "includes" but this gives an undefined error. https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-includes/

I also tried adding the code of an answer here on Stackoverflow; [find words in html page with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748309/find-words-in-html-page-with-javascript)

But this does not work within puppeteer, it only works when you paste it in the terminal. This system can only search for 1 word. My idea was to make an array that contains all words that must be filtered.

So far, I have written the following it. As far as I understood, to run code I need to put in into the {} of the evaluate().

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const id = new Date();
    console.log(id)
    await page.goto('https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/search.html?query=iphone&searchProfile=onlineshop&channel=mmnlnl', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    const html = await page.evaluate(() => {
         return page.includes("mediamarkt");
    });
    console.log(html)
    console.log("it worked, i guess");
})();
```

This generates errors like:

```
19-07-23T23:38:23.763Z
(node:24944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: page is not defined
```

My question for you is, how do I create a bad word filter using these tools or where can I learn more about the skills I need to build this.

Thank you

Comment: Try removing `await` from `const page = await browser.newPage();`. The error is that `page` is not getting defined properly. That's where you want to be focusing on.

Comment: I would also like to suggest you to check Marktplaats' API.

It could be a faster / more effective way to get to your result: https://api.marktplaats.nl/docs/v1/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to find all bad words (for example you have an array of bad words) and you want to check that page content contains any of bad words, you can do something like this:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const id = new Date();
  console.log(id)
  await page.goto('https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/search.html?query=iphone&searchProfile=onlineshop&channel=mmnlnl', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  const blackList = ['home', 'mediamarkt', 'sorteren', 'maakt'];

  const pageContent = await page.$eval('body', el => el.textContent);
  const result = pageContent.split(/\s+/).filter(text => blackList.includes(text.toLowerCase()));
  await browser.close();
  console.log("Here is the array of the found words", result);
})();
```

It will return the array of all found bad words on the page. Hope I get correctly your question.

Comment: Hello Yevhen, thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I shall use your code to teach myself how and why this works in my situation and implement this in further idea's I might have in the future.

Comment: Cool, happy to help you!)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find bad phrases (including spaces), you can try:

```
const found = await page.evaluate(() => window.find(elementsToSearchFor));
```

or

```
const found = (await page.content()).match(REGEX)
```