# Search text in WebView using Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, pdf, webview, epub

I currently have an application where I have to read books in epub format, I tried to use libraries like epub_kitty, but I had many errors with other libraries that I need. Anyway, I need my flutter application to search for a phrase within a webview, select (check) phrases for the user to open and view later, and bookmark the book.

One option that I’m currently testing is to take the html part of my epub and use my webview to show it to the user, but I don’t know how to do the functionality I imagined for the application (I’m currently trying to do the text search part inside the html, I'm trying to use a javascript code inside my webview but it isn't working), any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think that might work is using the Javascript... here's an example

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();    

Column(
    children: [
        FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
          future: _controller.future,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
            if (controller.hasData) {
              return FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Find "information"'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.data.evaluateJavascript('self.find("information")');
                  });
            }
            
            return SizedBox(height: 40);
          },
        ),
        Container(
          height: 400,
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

As you can see, by using the `evaluateJavascript` you can run the code you need to find the text. As for what you need, you can create a more complex function and add it to your html if needed. Then you can just invoke it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is already an advance in my application.

I read more about the javascript documentation and saw that this function cannot return the position of the word to me and thus I cannot get my user to be taken to it and I cannot even save that word for future searches.

Comment: Not sure how are you coding the search but you can take the query from there to store for your user. The JS function does return true|false if the query is found, so you can take it from there, if true, then the word is found and store whatever you have on your query.

Unless you want to know the exact position of the word? take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748309/find-words-in-html-page-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Youcan use`runJavascriptReturningResult` or `runJavascript` method over `webviewcontroller`

```
Return true if find a result or false (non-case search)

_controller!.runJavascriptReturningResult("self.find('bootstrap')")
.then((value) => print(value));
```

**Case Sensitive Search**

```
_controller!.runJavascript("self.find('Hi',{'CaseSensitive':true})");
```

> Syntax window.find(aString, aCaseSensitive, aBackwards, aWrapAround,
> aWholeWord, aSearchInFrames, aShowDialog); Copy to Clipboard aString The text string for which to search.
>
> aCaseSensitive A boolean value. If true, specifies a case-sensitive
> search.
>
> aBackwards A boolean value. If true, specifies a backward search.
>
> aWrapAround A boolean value. If true, specifies a wrap around search.
>
> aWholeWord Unimplemented A boolean value. If true, specifies a whole
> word search. This is not implemented; see bug 481513.
>
> aSearchInFrames A boolean value. If true, specifies a search in
> frames.
>
> Returns true if the string is found; otherwise, false.

[mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find#syntax)

**SampleCode**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (v) {
                          // _controller!
                          //     .runJavascriptReturningResult(
                          //     "self.find('${_textcontrol.text}')")
                          //     .then((value) => print(value));
                        },
                        controller: _textcontrol,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 55,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              var casesensitive =
                                  "self.find('${_textcontrol.text}',{'CaseSensitive':true})";
                              var noncase = "self.find('${_textcontrol.text}')";
                              _controller!.runJavascript(noncase);
                              // .then((value) => print(value));
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              size: 45,
                            )),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
              Expanded(
                  child: MyHomePage(
                title: '',
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

WebViewController? _controller;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  Color appBarcolor = Colors.blue;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

var _textcontrol = TextEditingController();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return controller();
  }

  WebView controller() {
    return WebView(
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialUrl: 'https://getbootstrap.com/',
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller = webViewController;
      },
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        setState(() {
          widget.appBarcolor = Colors.black87;
        });

        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: with the above code the search text is not getting highlighted. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: just checked in android, it is working in android and not in iOS. Any idea why?