# Search in WebView using search bar flutter

Tags: android, flutter, search, webview

I'm working on a flutter WebView project and I want to add a search bar to search elements inside my WebView. Any help is highly appreciated. Here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';   

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  WebViewController? webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: SafeArea(
       child : WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
        child : Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget> [
                WebView(
                  initialUrl: "https://google.com",
                  zoomEnabled: false,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller){
                    webViewController = controller;
                  },
               
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: do you want find text inside webview .or do you want search html element tag inside webview like chrome element

Comment: No I mean finding text inside webview

Comment: Check this, it might help you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63350672/search-text-in-webview-using-flutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Youcan use`runJavascriptReturningResult` or `runJavascript` method over `webviewcontroller`

```
_controller!.runJavascriptReturningResult("self.find('bootstrap')")
.then((value) => print(value));
```

**FullCode**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: _textcontrol,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Search', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 55,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _controller!.runJavascriptReturningResult("self.find('${_textcontrol.text}')").then((value) => print(value));
                            },
                            child: Text("Search")),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
              Expanded(
                  child: MyHomePage(
                title: '',
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

WebViewController? _controller;

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  Color appBarcolor = Colors.blue;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

var _textcontrol = TextEditingController();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return controller();
  }

  WebView controller() {
    return WebView(
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      initialUrl: 'https://getbootstrap.com/',
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller = webViewController;
      },
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        setState(() {
          widget.appBarcolor = Colors.black87;
        });

        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how do we find the text backwards ?